# How to get color settings of system UI (color theme) in Windows 10 with Python?

Tags: python, c++11, winapi

I'm trying to get some color settings in UI of Windows 10, e.g. colors of window title bar when windows are activated/inactivated, the edge color of window. Or to be more simple, I'm searching for a function like getSysColor() in winuser.h([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) in Windows 10.

[What I mean by "colors of window title bar when windows are activated" under "color settings in UI of Windows 10". (red circle)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaHjg.png)

Here's something I've tried:

1. `getSysColor(nIndex)` in winuser.h:

   This function cannot work well under Windows 10, for some keys(`nIndex`) are not supported according to the ([Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor?redirectedfrom=MSDN)) . For example, if I ask for the colors of activated window title bar with `ctypes.windll.user32.GetSysColor(2)` in Python, it will return the color of ##99B4D1, which is maybe the color under Windows 7, rather than the ##0078D7 in Windows 10. But **I don't want a color set of Windows 7**.
2. `DwmGetColorizationColor()` in dwmapi.h:

   Some suggest that this function may retrieve the color of title bar. But I can only get a strange yellow (##F8FFA9) with `ctypes.windll.dwmapi.DwmGetColorizationColor()`, which is definetly not what I want. Meanwhile this function can only offer color of title bar, rather than all the color used in Windows UI.

Comment: This information is exposed by the [`UISettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings) type. I don't know the specific platform requirements for this type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [UISettings::GetColorValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.getcolorvalue) with `UIColorType::Accent`.

Sadly the official Python/WinRT bindings don't support anything newer than Python 3.9 since they have been abandoned (and while you can use `RoGetActivationFactory` and friends directly, it's not convenient), but the community fork works quite well.

You need [winrt-Windows.UI](https://pypi.org/project/winrt-Windows.UI/) and [winrt-Windows.UI.ViewManagement](https://pypi.org/project/winrt-Windows.UI.ViewManagement/):

```py
from winrt.windows.ui.viewmanagement import UISettings, UIColorType

accent_color = UISettings().get_color_value(UIColorType.ACCENT)
print("accent color:", accent_color.r, accent_color.g, accent_color.b, accent_color.a)
```

Comment: The accent color is the base to derive several different color values. The color for specific UI elements is available through the [`UIElementColor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.uisettings.uielementcolor) method.

Comment: Sadly, it still offers the color of the light blue in Windows 7. (I've got `##99B4D1` again from `UISettings().u_i_element_color(UIElementType.ACTIVE_CAPTION)`)@IInspectable